# Omniauth error -- PG::Error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I've helped a friend add Omniauth to his app, and for some reason omniauth only worked the first time.

But now, it's returning:

```
     PG::Error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates 
    unique constraint "index_users_on_email" 
DETAIL: Key (email)=() already exists. : INSERT INTO "users" 
("created_at", "provider", "uid", "updated_at", "username") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

It's like it only accepts one, and then says "already exists". How can we get this workin'?

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :songs
  has_many :comments

  acts_as_voter

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = auth.info.nickname
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new session["devise.user_attributes"] do |user|
          user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank?
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def email_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end


end
```

**schema snippit**

```
 create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

**omni controller**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

All access keys are setup appropriately following railscasts latest ep on it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a unique constraint on the email field. Because this field is defined as not nullable and has a default value of "" (empty string). This means if you don't specify the email, your DBMS will set this field to "". Of course, because it has a unique constraint, you'll only be able to add two users without email, because only one can have the empty string email.

If you didn't create the constraint manually, then I assume rails has created it for you (because there's an index on the email field too apparently) by assuming the first field is the table primary key, since you didn't specify any. This made it create both an index and a unique constraint on it.

Comment: that makes sense. so, how do we fix it? i was thinkin' make the email field null maybe?

Comment: No, just declare the uid as the primary key (I suppose that's the real key). If the email should still be unique if set but you want to be able to leave it blank then don't declare it as not nullable and remove the default. This will set it to null if you don't use it the insert clause, and because in SQL, comparing null to null yields null, it won't break the unique restriction.

Comment: Ohhh.. I see. Can you please update your answer with example code and I will accept. I've never added a primary key before.

Comment: Having trouble adding the primary_key, what's the proper migration syntax for this type of thing?

Answer (score 2):

A more simple explanation could be that this is caused due to your test data being generated without a unique email. Try looking in /test/fixtures/users.yml, if you see something like:

```
one: {
}
two: {
}
```

then change it to

```
one: {
  email: tester1@stack.com
}
one: {
  email: tester2@stack.com
}
```

Or you can delete the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the index from the email since devise sets it as unique. You can't have duplicate blank email addresses according to how devise sets up things by default. Here is a migration example.

```
class ChangeEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :users, :email
  end
end
```